# What is the state of accelerated 3D and 2D graphics on RPi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero

I have read about RPi2 getting hardware accelerated OpenGL, but it seems that RPi Zero is not getting it.

What is the state of accelerated graphics on the Pi Zero? for 2D and 3D, be it a blob or Open Source with kernel support.

Thanks

Comment: OpenGL ES with the BLOB does work since 2011 , the Zero isn't different here . GLX/OpenGL are the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing missing for Pi0 specific support in the graphics driver as far as I know.  The Raspberry Pi foundation isn't exposing the open driver for the lower-memory boards currently, but that shouldn't stop a sufficiently motivated person.

For building support using the mainline kernel, you'd need a device tree for the Zero (http://www.spinics.net/lists/devicetree/msg113029.html) and device tree for VC4 (start from https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2016-March/102276.html) and then use bcm2835_defconfig.  Hopefully I get both of these merged for 4.7.

Note that you need to get the HDMI DT bits from another board into your new bcm2835-rpi-zero.dts in order for monitor detection to work.  You want the _LOW variant from bcm2836-rpi-2-b.dts.  And, since you're LOW, you want the vc4 fix for LOW boards (https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/2/29/839 which is merged for 4.6)

Caveat: I don't have a Zero to test with so this is all just what *should* work.

Comment: Well, a much more elaborated answer than I could expect. Thanks a lot.